# help with under/overclocking [problem with coolbits and Xorg.conf file]

Tags: boot, xorg.conf, overclocking

I've recently gotten into Ethereum mining and I have run into an issue that I cannot solve. I want to under clock my gpu and in order to do so I am using the application "Green with envy". However I am running into a serious problem with the Xorg.conf file

I am using this command `sudo nvidia-xconfig --cool-bits=12`

it then generates the xorg.conf file in /ect/X11

However upon restart it does not boot and I had to delete the file in recovery mode.

I then tried to follow these instructions https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/ca57ns/what_is_the_replacement_for_xorgconf_want_to_set/

However upon restart it again did not boot and this time I had to do a complete reinstall of ubuntu.

My question is how to I edit cool bits without breaking boot/ how do I enable overclocking in general without breaking boot.

I am running ubuntu 20.04

Thanks for any help you can give me and let me know if there is anything I can clarify. I am very new to all of this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

May not work for you but it worked for me on Pop_OS 21.04 x64. I followed the same reddit page you have linked but instead of copying the entire xorg.conf file into the xorg.conf.d folder. I ended up having to just extract the section about the coolbits and deleting every other bit. I'll copy and paste my one but beware it may be different to your own file.

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Coolbits" "12"
    SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Still save the file name as directed in the reddit post eg. 20-nvidia.conf.
Hope this helps.